# FME list index number as attribute value

Tags: fme-form, list

I have a created list that has the same road name but several separate segments. These have been sorted using the length of road lines (with `ListSorter`). The list index inside `()` shows the order of the roads according to their lenght. I need to save this list index as an attribute. How can I save the list index as an attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListExploder solve my problem. It creates "_element_index" where is that needed index number.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the attributes of the listelements with index = 0?

You can do this using an AttributeCreator:
gid = _list{0}.gid
etc

[image: AttributeCreator Parameters]

Comment: I want to create new attribute "list_index" which has value "0" in this case